# how to open xbap file?

Tags: wpf, clickonce, xbap

how can I open .xbap file downloaded from internet?
many Control vendor sites offers to download .xbap file to show WPF controls, but I cant Open them.
Internet Explorer generates error:

http://img28.imageshack.us/i/capturenxs.png/

Error Log:

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [3/31/2011 2:23:10 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Exception reading manifest from file:///E:/Downloads/ControlExplorer.xbap: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.

- Source: System.Deployment
      - Stack trace:
          at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
          at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirect(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
          at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifest(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
          at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.BindCore(Boolean blocking, TempFile& tempDeploy, TempDirectory& tempAppDir, FileStream& refTransaction, String& productName)
          at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.BindAsyncWorker()
      --- Inner Exception ---
      System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (SignatureValidation)
      - Manifest XML signature is not valid.
- Source: System.Deployment
      - Stack trace:
          at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream s)
          at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
      --- Inner Exception ---
      System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
      - No signature was present in the subject.
- Source: System.Deployment
      - Stack trace:
          at System.Deployment.Internal.CodeSigning.SignedCmiManifest.Verify(CmiManifestVerifyFlags verifyFlags)
          at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream s)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have .Net 3.5 SP1 installed? The original version of 3.5 did not allow unsigned applications.

Comment: I have net framework 4.0 installed on Windows 7 Professional N. I've tried in IE 8, in Firefox 3, and in Chrome without success.
On XP machine with net framework 4.0 there was no problem to open xbap even in  IE 6.0

Comment: I cannot open on Windows 10 :(